# how to disable USB devices based on vendor id in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I want to disable usb devices based on vendor id in Linux environment. I want to allow only specific USB devices, based on vendor id.

Comment: How to Block USB/PEN DRIVE in Linux (kali linux) http://grprajapat.blogspot.in/2014/09/how-to-disable-usbpen-drive-in-linux.html

Comment: I have one specific vendor:device ID I want to disable cdc_acm for. I have since [made this into a separate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165686/43720).

Answer (score 18):

You can make a udev rule that disables devices by default, but enables certain ones by vendor ID. Make a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/01-usblockdown.rules` that contains a rule to disable devices:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'for host in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*; do echo 0 > $host/authorized_default; done'"
```

And then rules to enable the devices you want to allow (you can use `ATTR{idVendor}` to get at the vendor ID):

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0000" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
```

See ["Locking down Linux using UDEV"](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/plug-and-prey-malicious-usb-devices#3.2_Locking_down_Linux_using_UDEV) for more information.

Comment: is the above command is enough or we have to do any udevadm trigger to get effect of this.

Comment: hi Stephane, we have to add both rules to allow specific pendrive?

Comment: @subbarao Yes, you have to add both rules, the first blocks anything per default, the second allows certain devices.

Comment: This works for when you plug in, say a keyboard, once the system is booted.  But if the keyboard is connected and you reboot, the keyboard works upon the OS booting back up.  Unplugging the keyboard then re-plug, the keyboard doesn't work as expected.  Is there some area more lower level that this rule can be run before boot devices are activated?

Answer (score 7):

(this might have been better as a comment but I lack the points so expanded it into an answer)

I came here searching for how to allow all usb devices except disabling a specific one by vendor and product id.  [How to disable a usb sound device with udev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105694/how-to-disable-a-usb-sound-device-with-udev) answers it for the 0d8c:000c example.

Create `/etc/udev/rules.d/disable-usb-device.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0d8c", ATTR{idProduct}=="000c", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```

There a discrepancy between the answer and a comment below with `RUN=` vs. `RUN+=`, I tried the former and it worked fine.

I was expecting dmesg or lusb to report differently but they both show the un-authorized device getting enumerated just as before, but other processes/modules that would have launched automatically appear to not be running which was the desired effect. `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2.2.1.1.4/authorized` (the 1-2.2... for example which can be found in dmesg) shows that the 0 was put in the right place.

Comment: I don't know if there was some changes in-between in udev, but nowadays attributes are named `ATTRS` (plural) and not `ATTR` when I query devices with `udevadm`.

Comment: It is `ATTR` for the attributes of the exact device udev is focusing on, and `ATTRS` for attributes belonging to its parent devices.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that the "idVendor" and "idProduct" can be found with `lsusb` .. they are the 2 sets of 4 hexadecimal numbers separated by `:`, left side is vendor, right side is product, so e.g. `0bda:8153` -> `0bda` for `idVendor` and `8153` for `idProduct`.

Comment: idk why, but i had to change this a little bit to make it work on debian bullseye. here is my udev.rule: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8771", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/$env{DEVPATH}/authorized'" `

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/81-elan-fingerprint.rules
# ID 04f3:0c28 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint should be disabled
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="04f3", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c28", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/\$devpath/remove'"
```

This makes the usb device unusuable, as it's removed as soon as is plugged in, removing 'ATTR{idProduct}=="0c28",' should do the same for all devices from that vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  Can you [edit] your question and add a little explanation about what part of your answer solves the question?  Thanks.