# How to disable a usb sound device with udev

Tags: linux, udev, audio

How can I disable USB device by Vendor ID? So I have:

```
[root@piotr ~]# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:9254 Alcor Micro Corp. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bc2:3320 Seagate RSS LLC SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
```

I want to disable

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
```

I need this unit in Windows environment but it disturb me Skype input (and only Skype). As temporary solution I just included snd_usb_audio in modprobe blacklist. But it is only workaround.
Or, (maybe better) is it possible to exclude this particular USB device from udev rules?  But in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d there is not definition for this device. I mean about VendorID.

So my questions are:
Why it is working at all and can be seen by ALSA?
How can I exclude such VendorID and ProductID fron udev rules?
Any idea wanted

Comment: you should edit your title to make it more general like how to ban a usb device with udev or something like this

Answer (score 3):

Correct answer (based on feedback from @mackowiakp) is actually this:

Add this line:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0d8c", ATTR{idProduct}=="000c", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```

to a new file (ex: my.rules) in /etc/udev/rules.d/

Differences from @user2438863's answer:

- `RUN=` instead of `RUN+=`
- `echo 0` instead of `echo 1`

Comment: Thanks @joachime-saur -- fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Add this line:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0d8c", ATTR{idProduct}=="000c", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```

to a new file (ex: my.rules) in /etc/udev/rules.d/

Comment: Hmmm. It does not work for me. My device path is:

    /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/sound/card1

And suggested by You rule entry, does not create "authorized" file in such path.

I think that some kind of default rule still activate my (unwanted) USB sound device, becuse in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/ there is not any definition for such Vendor and Product ID. My system does not use /etc/udev as rules definition subdir.
So some modification is necessary. What to do?

Comment: OK. You help me. But correct syntax should be   ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0d8c", ATTR{idProduct}=="000c", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"  --- THX