# How to disable USB Keyboard at run time from udev.c not from udev rules

Tags: linux, keyboard, udev

I want to disable my USB keyboard at boot time (in some scenarios) without modifying `udev` rules, as I know `udev` rules only works when a device is attached or detached from the target.

Is there any option in "udev.c" or in `udev` rules by which I can disable my USB keyboard at boottime?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying udev rules is actually the way to go. Udev rules are applied when the device is attached, but that includes devices that are already attached when the system boots: once udev has started, it applies all the rules to already-connected devices.

So write a [udev rule that declares your keyboard as not authorized](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment/63237#63237).