# How to disable USB devices based on their vendor ID on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, devices, udev, nxt

In [that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63199/43720) someone wanted a blacklist for all USB devices, and then only allow specific devices.

In this question, we want to accept all USB devices, but prevent the driver (e.g. `cdc_acm`) from taking one specific device type – for example, an [LEGO® NXT brick](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/) in flash mode should not be taken (because `fwflash` needs raw access to the device), but an Arduino board should still be accessed by the driver to produce `/dev/ttyACM0`, in an [educative environment](https://www.teckids.org/dienste.htm) accessing both NXT and Arduino hardware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve been able to do this with an udev rule, after some trickery (and using `lsusb` to find out the vendor and product ID of the device in flash mode):

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/nxt.rules
# disable NXT in flash mode
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6124", RUN="/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo -n $kernel:1.0 | /usr/bin/tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cdc_acm/unbind | /usr/bin/logger -t nxt-flashmode'"
```

This rule is triggered when an NXT brick is plugged in while in flash mode, or put into flash mode while plugged in. It does not prevent `cdc_acm` from grabbing it, but immediately after tells it to release the device, so `fwflash` can access it.

I have not found out what the `:1.0` is, and why use that and not `:1.1` which also shows up in sysfs. However, I wanted to share a working (for me) solution. Environment: Debian unstable as of end of October, 2014 (i.e. pretty much Debian jessie).

Comment: In more recent kernels you can come at with more directly, with a rule like `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6124", ATTR{authorized}="0"` which will unauthorise (and likely power down the device) within the kernel.

Comment: @vk5tu that fails the question: a different driver needs to access that device, in raw mode.