# Disable embedded keyboard when in a tty

Tags: linux, keyboard, console, devices, input

I've been lately working on a netbook.
I like to connected an external keyboard and mouse to it whenever I can, and I put the keyboard over the embedded keyboard.

When on X, I used xinput to disable the embedded keyboard like so to prevent the overlayed keyboard from pressing the embeded one (or more accurately, from preventing those presses from having an effect):

```
#!/bin/sh
usage(){
    : ${SELF:="$(basename "$0")"}
cat <<EOF
Usage:
    $SELF 
        Query state of X device
    $SELF 0|1
        Set state of X device
    $SELF -h|--help
        Show this help
EOF
}
[ $# -gt 1 ] && { usage >&2; exit 1; }

acerKbd=$(
xinput --list 2>/dev/null|
xinput  --list | sed -n 's/^.*AT Translated Set 2 keyboard.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/ p'
)
queryState(){ xinput list-props "$acerKbd" |grep 'Device Enabled'|cut -d: -f2|tr -d ' \t'; }
setState() { xinput set-int-prop "$acerKbd" 'Device Enabled' 8 "$1"; }

case "$1" in
    -h|--help) usage;;
    0|1) setState "$1";;
    "") queryState;;
    *) usage >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

I use virtually the same script for disabling/enabling the mouse (different searching strategy -- I don't know if there's a better way to target the device than by regexp matching `xinput`'s output).

But I have yet to find a way to do the tty equivalent of this?

Any ideas?

Comment: There's a [mechanism to disable individual USB devices](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment/63237#63237), and there's a mechanism to blacklist drivers if they're loaded as modules, but I don't know how to disable a specific non-USB device.