# Raspbian disable mount & automount USB storage

Tags: linux, mount, usb-drive, raspbian, removable-storage

I have installed Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi. Due to the security policy in the company, we would like to block access to USB mass storage (pendrives, usb drives, etc.). I tried according to this article: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=91677 with the option:

`chattr +i ~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/pcmanfm.conf`

however, each entry in the file explorer options and change mount parameters makes it easily possible to use the storage. Is there any way to permanently block the ability to mount removable media?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment

Comment: Trying to block access to USB drives via the file manager is an approach that is bound to fail. Users can always launch a different file manager or access the drive from command line.