# Execute script on external keyboard connection

Tags: shell-script, keyboard, udev, xkb

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate because the linked question is about external USB **drives**, not **keyboards**. The suggested command `udevadm info -a -n sdb` does nothing in helping to find the corresponding attributes for the **keyboard**.

After spending more than an hour on this, eventually I tried the following, which is unlikely to be accurate:

```
SUBSYSTEMS="input", RUN+="/home/jx/Dropbox/scripts/keyboard.sh %p"
SUBSYSTEMS="hid", RUN+="/home/jx/Dropbox/scripts/keyboard.sh %p"
SUBSYSTEMS="usb", RUN+="/home/jx/Dropbox/scripts/keyboard.sh %p"
```

However, it only worked when I first start up the computer. Whenever I unplug the keyboard and reconnect it later, the script **doesn't** get executed automatically.

How can I find the attributes for the keyboard and how do I ensure the script gets every time the keyboard is connected, even when the OS is already running?

---

I'm performing two modifications on my keyboard on startup:

```
xset r rate 160 50 
setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"
```

However, they seem to be lost whenever I disconnect my external USB keyboard (sometimes I switch the keyboard between machines), and I always have to re-execute the commands whenever I reconnect it, which is quite annoying.

Is there a way to let the system detect the keyboard connection event and execute a custom script upon it?

Or maybe, alternatively, find a way to keep those two settings permanent even after restart.

I am on Arch Linux with systemd.

Comment: Note that the "duplicate" question doesn't exactly solve my question since it's about external USB drives, but I couldn't easily find the attributes for my USB keyboard to match against. The page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#List_the_attributes_of_a_device helps

Comment: You probably want to use the "Vendor:Device" attribute... similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment/63237) ... `lsusb` should show the hexidecimal pair to use... and `udevadm monitor -k` should show you what changes each time you unplug the keyboard and plug it back in again...

Comment: Greetings from July 2023. I have the exact same issue when re/connecting my Planck. Did you ever find any robust solution to this?